# How Do I Get Folder Names From C# Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, sorting, embedded-resource

I want to order resources the way a filesystem would order them. I can't do a string.split on the name, because the folders are seperated by '.' characters, not '\' characters. This means that having any periods in folder or file names would break the sort.

Is there any way to change the seperator character, or get a different breakdown for the original location of an embedded resource?

Answer (score -1):

This will get you a string array of all the resources.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```